# QNX Momentic IDE - QML Preview is disabled

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, qnx

I'm trying to learn BB10 development so I tried downloading their QNX Momentic IDE.

Whenever I run the application, it always pops up a message saying "QML Preview compatibility check  failed. QML Preview is disabled." which obviously is the reason why my Design Mode is disabled.

I search for this problem in the net and found similar cases, most cases I found on the net is mostly related to Java version so I tried several versions (1.6, 1.7), I also tried the solution in the thread I found here [QML Preview compatibility check failed. QML preview is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876907/qml-preview-compatibility-check-failed-qml-preview-is-disabled), but it still doesn't work. So tried the other suggestion to look at the C:\Documents and Settings\user\ndk-10.1.0-workspace.metadata.log file to see what's really causing the problem, and I found out that I have different error thrown than the other cases I found on the net.

```
Here's the error:

!SESSION 2013-02-22 23:09:38.515 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=10.1.0
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-02-22 23:09:42.781
!MESSAGE Plug-in 'com.rim.tad.tools.qml.javascript.debug.internal.ui' contributed an  invalid Menu Extension (Group: 'jsdebug' is invalid): com.rim.tad.tools.wst.jsdt.debug.ui.jsunit.popup.evaluate

!ENTRY com.rim.tad.tools.qml.core 2 0 2013-02-22 23:09:43.234
!MESSAGE Cannot resolve ValueType variant: Number

!ENTRY com.rim.tad.tools.qml.core 2 0 2013-02-22 23:09:43.234
!MESSAGE Cannot resolve ValueType variant: QLocale

!ENTRY com.rim.tad.tools.qml.core 2 0 2013-02-22 23:09:43.234
!MESSAGE Cannot resolve ValueType variant: String

!ENTRY com.rim.tad.tools.qml.core 2 0 2013-02-22 23:09:43.250
!MESSAGE Cannot resolve ValueType variant: bb::device::CellularService::Types

!ENTRY com.rim.tad.tools.qml.core 2 0 2013-02-22 23:09:43.250
!MESSAGE Cannot resolve ValueType variant: Boolean

!ENTRY com.rim.tad.tools.qml.core 2 0 2013-02-22 23:09:43.250
!MESSAGE Cannot resolve ValueType variant:  bb::system::SystemUiButton 

!ENTRY com.rim.tad.tools.qml.core 2 0 2013-02-22 23:09:43.250
!MESSAGE Issues while loading Components Definition:
Duplicate Signal in: ComponentID: bb::cascades::InvokeActionItem, Signal: handlerChanged


!ENTRY com.rim.tad.tools.qml.simulator 1 0 2013-02-22 23:09:44.703
!MESSAGE C:\bbndk\ide\win32\x86\eclipse\jre\bin\java.exe -cp C:\bbndk\ide\win32\x86\eclipse\plugins\com.rim.tad.tools.qml.simulator_10.1.0.201302011933\ com.rim.tad.tools.qml.sim.check.RenderingCheck -target C:\bbndk\target_10_1_0_338\qnx6

!ENTRY com.rim.tad.tools.qml.simulator 4 0 2013-02-22 23:09:45.546
!MESSAGE QML Preview compatibility check log.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: glGetProcAddress_win32 failed: glGenFramebuffersEXT
at com.rim.tad.tools.qml.sim.CsApplicationEngine.nExec(Native Method)
at     com.rim.tad.tools.qml.sim.CsApplicationEngine.execAndDestroy(CsApplicationEngine.java:45)
at     com.rim.tad.tools.qml.sim.CsApplicationEngineThread.run(CsApplicationEngineThread.java:55)
Warning: WARNING: QApplication was not created in the main() thread.

Process exited with code: -1

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2013-02-22 23:13:26.140
!MESSAGE A handler conflict occurred.  This may disable some commands.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui.workbench 2 0 2013-02-22 23:13:26.140
!MESSAGE Conflict for     'AUTOGEN:::org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.actionSet/org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.actions.CheatSheetHelpMenuAction':
         HandlerActivation(commandId=AUTOGEN:::org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.actionSet/org.eclipse.ui.c    heatsheets.actions.CheatSheetHelpMenuAction,
        handler=ActionDelegateHandlerProxy(null,org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.CheatSheetExtensionFacto    ry:helpMenuAction),
        expression=AndExpression(ActionSetExpression(org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.actionSet,org.eclip        se.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@2585e),WorkbenchWindowExpression(org.eclipse.ui.internal.Wor    kbenchWindow@2585e)),sourcePriority=16640)
    HandlerActivation(commandId=AUTOGEN:::org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.actionSet/org.eclipse.ui.c    heatsheets.actions.CheatSheetHelpMenuAction,
    handler=ActionDelegateHandlerProxy(null,org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.CheatSheetExtensionFacto    ry:helpMenuAction),
    expression=AndExpression(ActionSetExpression(org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets.actionSet,org.eclip    se.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow@2585e),WorkbenchWindowExpression(org.eclipse.ui.internal.Wor    kbenchWindow@2585e)),sourcePriority=16640)
```

Now, I don't know what to make of this error and much more how to fix it. If anyone one is familiar, I would appreciate if you could throw in some inputs or point me to the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, the check seems to be executed when starting up the simulator plugin, looks like we have to wait for BlackBerry to make the fix :S

Answer (score 1):

When I have encountered this issue it has always been a graphics driver problem. You might want to ensure you have the latest drivers loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Check the java version, could be your JVM does not support -d32.